# How to return data FROM HttpPost to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I've been passed a specification that is requesting to use an HttpPost request and receive **back** data - looking from the spec as if it is Form data.

My current WebApi implementation doesn't return any data from the HttpPost request, just the HttpResponse.OK (200) and the location to navigate to.

I've tried a very simple formatter, but this returns xml:

```
var baseResponse = new BaseResponse() { Something = "Fred" };
HttpResponseMessage response = this.Request.CreateResponse<BaseResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, baseResponse);
return response;
```

and if I add the `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to the method then I receive back an error:

`Could not find a formatter matching the media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

The sped document shows Key/Value pairs...so I could either generate these as a string, or implement a custom formatter?

```
e.g.
Header = blah blah 200 OK
Data = Something=Fred&SomethingElse=NotFred&AnotherThing=Banana
```

However, is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In an ASP.NET MVC website, your controller method handling the Post would return `ActionResult`.  The ActionResult could be a JsonResult which could have named parameters.

In WebAPI, you could do something similar by [implementing `IHttpActionResult`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) to emulate ActionResult.

Comment: I can return Json (and format as xml or json) but this is not what the specification I have been given shows :(   As per the Q above, the spec (from a govt agency) shows this as Form data ?!?!